# При помощи Github Actions отправляю запрос curl и получаю Connection timed out

Tags: curl, github-actions

Сделал простой Github Actions, который отправляет curl запрос

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Run curl
        env:
          LOGIN: ${{ secrets.LOGIN }}
          PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}
        run: curl 'https://lk.ttk.ru/api/auth/loginByAccount' -d '{"login":"$LOGIN","password":"$PASSWORD"}'
```

В результате получаю

```
curl: (28) Failed to connect to lk.ttk.ru port 443 after 131128 ms: Connection timed out
Error: Process completed with exit code 28.
```

Если выполнять curl с домашнего ПК все работает, в чем может быть проблема и как ее решить?